# Why does this test only fail when there is a rejection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sinon

This test passes; i.e. sinon says the stub is in fact, called:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon')

async function underTest (s){
  promise1 = new Promise((yes, no)=>yes())
  promise2 = new Promise((yes, no)=>yes())

  Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(s.yes).catch(s.no)
}

async function test(){
  s = {yes: sinon.stub(), no:sinon.stub()}  
  await underTest(s)
  sinon.assert.called(s.yes)
}

test().then(console.log('done'))
```

Note how I did not return a promise from `Promise.all`.

However, the following test will fail, and sinon will say the stub was NOT called:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon')

async function underTest (s){
  promise1 = new Promise((yes, no)=>no())
  promise2 = new Promise((yes, no)=>no())

  Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(s.yes).catch(s.no)
}

async function test(){
  s = {yes: sinon.stub(), no:sinon.stub()}  
  await underTest(s)
  sinon.assert.called(s.no)
}

test().then(console.log('done'))
```

And if I return the `Promise.all`, then it will pass, and sinon will say the `s.no` stub is called:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon')

async function underTest (s){
  promise1 = new Promise((yes, no)=>no())
  promise2 = new Promise((yes, no)=>no())

  return Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(s.yes).catch(s.no)
}

async function test(){
  s = {yes: sinon.stub(), no:sinon.stub()}  
  await underTest(s)
  sinon.assert.called(s.no)
}

test().then(console.log('done'))
```

It makes sense that the test only passes if I return the promise from `Promise.all`. If I return nothing the `async` function will resolve to `undefined` and the stub might or might not have been called.

My question is, I would have expected the test to fail, in case there is no return statement, even for the first case, where the promises resolve. I would have expected for sinon to tell me `s.yes` was not called. But why does it pass? Why is there inconsistency between resolve and reject?

Answer (score 1):

I run your code. No. Your first code / case test is done, but the result is not passed.

You have better way of knowing it if you also implement catch when run the test something like this:

```
test()
.then(() => console.log('done'))
.catch((error) => console.log('Error:', error.message));
```

You are using async await inconsistently.

If you are using async await, you can catch the error using [try and catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch).

For example:

```
async function underTest (s){
  promise1 = new Promise((yes, no)=>yes())
  promise2 = new Promise((yes, no)=>yes())

  try {
    await Promise.all([promise1, promise2]);
    s.yes();
  } catch {
    s.no();
  }
  // This will return Promise<void>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time. But as you can gather, Sinon says, in the first case, that s.yes is in fact called. while s.no is not called. It should be that not using await should cause both cases to fail not just one, right?

Comment: I edited my answer after you comment to add example. No. the first case s.yes not called. The first case output error in my terminal: Error: expected stub to have been called at least once but was never called

Comment: Wow you're right, now it is not running anymore.